# Error in React Redux: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am receiving the following error when making a fetch call and sending some values via the connect function in react redux into the store.

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

I saw a couple of questions about this error but none of them were close enough to my case and my ability to understand the problem. I read about using of "thunk" in some cases but in other cases people referred to this error as something that is just not set up right in redux, so I am not sure what is the case here exactly.

This is the fetch call made in the Chat.js class:

```
async sendAtStart() {
 var msg;
    await fetch(
      '*********',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ inputText: 'hello' })
      }
    )
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => {
        msg = r.msg;


      });

    this.props.addMessage(msg);
  }
```

This is the connect function at the end of Chat.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addMessage: () => dispatch(addMessage)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Chat);
```

This is the store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import MessageReducer from './reducers/MessageReducer';
function configureStore(state = { text: '', key: '' }) {
  return createStore(MessageReducer, state);
}
export default configureStore;
```

Actions:

```
export function addMessage(text) {
  return { type: 'addMessage', text };
}
```

Reducers:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addMessage':
      return {
        text: action.text
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Where exactly is the problem in my case ?

Comment: When you console.log(r.msg) what do you get?

Comment: A text response, the fetch call is indeed working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addMessage: () => dispatch(addMessage)
});
```

Here you forget to set the parameter in the alias, it should be :

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   addMessage: (msg) => dispatch(addMessage(msg))
 });
```

Comment: Thanks,It seems to get rid of the problem. Though it still seems like the state (defined at the constructor by:  this.state = {
      chats: []
    };) is not getting updated and stays undefined.

Comment: I don't see where you are doing a this.setState() but I don't know saga, just so you know :)

Comment: How should I approach updating the state after dispatching a message to the store ?, how do I retrieve the data that was entered to the store ?

Comment: When the store update due to a dispatch, you can be notified via mapStateToProps

You should think mapDispatchToProps as a function to write in the store and mapStateToProps a function to read from the store ( it put the store data inside your component props)

Answer (score 0):

you cant do async actions easily without middleware like redux-saga or redux-thunk. my suggestion is use redux-saga for async actions like fetch.